# VB6 'Out of memory' Can compile on one machine but not another

Tags: vb6, out-of-memory

So here is a problem that took almost an entire day to resolve. Figured I would give what happened to my and how I resolved it in case other users still use this old of software.

So some columns were added to the TrueDBGrid on a local machine. This gets pushed over to another machine after testing to build the product and have it ready to be deployed. After adding in all the columns verifying the changes made everything worked everything was pushed over to the computer that handles production.

These changes include logic changes, adding additional global variables, modifying dataEnviornments, and a few other small changes. When the changes were pushed over to the machine is when the 'out of memory' error occurred. Additionally other projects were modified that did not contain this issue. And as far as the compiler cared it stated that the error came from a user32.dll. So thats were are issues occured.

I will add some additional things that were tried before posting the answer below.

Things that we read up on and tried include verifying that all the dll's that we believe that may have been the cause were not registered.(Partly because this new production computer had changed recently and not all portions of our product had been built on it yet) Also learned that its not uncommon from my understanding that if a dll is contained in the registry as a known dll and when a program tries to access it through other programs windows will attempt to user the known dll before searching outside of that area.

Verifying that all our paths were correct and all those files actually existed for all dll's were considered as a possible problem.

Verifying that We had sufficient memory to run all things needed. This was removed as a possibility for a one major reason. Tracking the task managers performance should no spikes that ever got close to reaching max capacity.

Also we attempted in moving the project on the production machine to one of our development machines and the same issue was created. Taking the same code from our production machine through other means that didnt involve the normal process. And both created the issue. This lead us to believe something on the production machine was the actual source of the issue.

This was all done yesterday so I may have missed some things we attempted to do but from other research we did learn its not uncommon for visual basic to throw an 'out of memory' error for an error that has nothing to do with that.

Below is how we resolved this issue. Though I'm not quite sure how this cause the issue and how I would go about creating it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did to fix this.

I figured that since we modified the data Environment and we knew memory and global variables were most likely not the issue as we have other applications using many more variables or much larger in size and they all worked fine but this is the first time someone that still worked here has modified the data Environment that it was the next thing in our diminishing list of things to try to fix the issue.

We reverted the data environment and datagrid back to how it was before as well as it was broken to verify that worked. 
Which it did work.

Based off that we modified the the data environment on the production build to mimic what was done on the development side of things and we were able to successfully compile.

One thought my mentor had was that the versions are different on some level of the dll's that our development side has but now our production side. That caused the changes to happen in a way that the production wasn't able to handle properly.

So TLDR the data environment change caused the 'out of memory' error that worked on most machines but not at least one other.

Comment: What, exactly, does "data environment" mean? In other words, what specifically did you change / change back?

Comment: It's kind of lengthy and its not something I know much about to summarize but here is a link that describes what a DataEnviornment and what it is used for https://free-visualbasic-tutor.blogspot.com/2011/07/data-environment.html.

I added an edit to include the datagrid as well. However, I removed the new columns from the datagrid that was created on our dev computer as well as i removed the added fields I had created in the data environment to be able to hold the new values for the new columns. On the production side I then recreated these columns and fields.

Comment: None of the code outside of the data environment and datagrid needed to be changed. In more details 8 columns and 8 fields were added to the datagrid -> (UI the user can be allowed to see on the app) and data enviornment  -> (Connection to the local mdb).